# Scala - return a function from a map

Tags: scala, dictionary

In scala, how would i declare & instantiate a map that returns a function (for the sake of argument? A function that accepts two variables, one a String, one an Int)?

I am envisioning:

```
val myMap = Map[String, (String,Int)=>Boolean](
    WHAT GOES HERE???
)
```

Let's just map the  string "a" to this cool function. I don't care much about what the function does - returns true, perhaps?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
  val myMap = Map[String, (String, Int) => Boolean](
    "Test" -> ((s, i)  => true)
  )
```

Comment: presto! thanks. I was putting curly brackets and defining the inputs

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this:

```
val map = Map("key" -> { (str: String, n: Int) =>
  str.indexOf(n) == -1
})
```

result:

```
> map: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,(String, Int) => Boolean] = Map(key - <function2>)
```